# validation for integer and float values in php

Tags: php

Im checking for validation for both integer and float.
preg('/^[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?$/',$str)
This works fine
12,12.05
But not for .12

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
kumar.

Answer (score 5):

Make that

```
preg('/^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?$/',$str)
```

`+` means the element will be repeated one or more times, `*` means it will be repeated zero or more times.

Comment: You need to escape `.`, and this regex matches empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Yep try this:

```
if((int) $str != $str)
{
    //error
}

if((float) $str != $str)
{
    //error
}
```

This should do the trick, and I suppose it will work faster than the regex. Additonally you can check after that `(float) $str <= 0` -> another error, etc.

I would bet on regex for more complicated validations, where the with standard routines you have to write some chunk of code, such as email validation, mask(pattern) input and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of [is_float](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) and [is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

however, both are pretty much covered by [is_numeric](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

```
<?php
$tests = array(
    "42", 
    1337, 
    "1e4", 
    "not numeric", 
    array(), 
    9.1
);

foreach ($tests as $element) {
    if (is_numeric($element)) {
        echo "'{$element}' is numeric", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "'{$element}' is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
'42' is numeric
'1337' is numeric
'1e4' is numeric
'not numeric' is NOT numeric
'Array' is NOT numeric
'9.1' is numeric
```

Is Float Example:

```
<?php
if (is_float(27.25)) {
    echo "is float\n";
} else {
    echo "is not float\n";
}
var_dump(is_float('abc'));
var_dump(is_float(23));
var_dump(is_float(23.5));
var_dump(is_float(1e7));  //Scientific Notation
var_dump(is_float(true));
?>
is float
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

and Is_int example:

```
<?php
if (is_int(23)) {
    echo "is integer\n";
} else {
    echo "is not an integer\n";
}
var_dump(is_int(23));
var_dump(is_int("23"));
var_dump(is_int(23.5));
var_dump(is_int(true));
?>
is integer
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$regex = '~^(\d+)|(\d+)?\.(\d+)$~';
$input = array( '12', '12.05', '.12' );

foreach( $input as $string ) {
    echo "Match " . ( preg_match( $regex, $string ) !== 0 ? "OK" : "NOT OK" ) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **is_float** and **is_int** function of PHP to validate number..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `is_numeric` function in PHP that has very better **performance** than `regex` functions.

`is_numeric` return true for ALL of these items:

1. integer `$s = 123;`
2. string that contain integer `$s = '123';`
3. float integer `$s = 123.456;`
4. float integer whitout leading zero `$s = '.456';`
5. negative number `$s = '-.456';`

you can see it in action [here](https://eval.in/294562).